# How to append an element to each element of a list ? (Prolog)

Tags: prolog

I'll like to append an element to each element of a list. the element must be a list too.

Exemple :

```
A = [a,b,c]
B = [ele,ele2]
```

The result would be:

```
R = [[a,ele,ele2],[b,ele,ele2],[c,ele,ele2]]
```

I tried

```
 maplist(custom_append,A,B,R).
```

But it returns false with

```
custom_append(X,Y,[X|Y]).
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `B` is not a list over which you want to *iterate*, you want to append an element of `A` to the same list `B`.

The easiest way to achieve this, is probably by swapping the order of the elements in the `custom_append/3` to:

```
custom_append(Y, X, [X|Y]).
```

and then we can obtain this by using a `maplist/3`:

```
maplist(custom_append(B), A, R).
```

we thus already make something that behaves quite similar to *partial application*: we pass a functor `custom_append(B)`, and Prolog will then make a call with `custom_append(B, Ai, Ri)` (`Ai` and `Ri` are here used to denote the elements of the lists `A` and `R`).

Comment: I learnt something today ! Very usefull. I misunderstood how worked maplist.

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way would be like this:

```
append_list([], _, []).

append_list([A|As], B, [[A|B]|Cs]) :-
    append_list(As, B, Cs).
```

Don't even need to use `maplist`.

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged; please include an explanation of how and why this answers the question.